# Prolog change for 100 cents

Tags: prolog, clpfd, coin-change

I am new to Prolog and I want to write a function that returns all different ways to make change for a dollar (100 cents). We have 2-cent coins, 11-cent coins, 38-cent coins, and, interestingly,  -8-cent coins (a coin worth -8 cents). Also we only have 10 pieces of "-8" cent coins in total. (no upper bound for other kinds of coins)

Here is my try:

```
change100([P2, P11, P38, Pn8]):- 
    Pn8 =< 10,
    Pn8 >= 0,
    P2 >= 0, P11 >= 0, P38 >= 0,
    D is 2 * P2 + 11 * P11 + 38 * P38 - 8 * Pn8,
    D = 100.
```

But it doesn't work. When I run it and query

```
?- change100(A).
```

I got message

```
ERROR:

=< /2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.
```

Why is this? How can I fix it?

---

#### The original problem statement:

> There are 4 kinds of coins: a 2-cent piece, an 11-cent piece, a 38-cent piece, and, interestingly, a -8-cent piece (a coin worth -8 cents). Even more interesting, a total of only 10 -8- cent pieces have ever been created, so you never need to worry about situations with more than 10 -8-cent pieces.
>
> How many different ways can you make change for a dollar (100 cents)?
>
> For example, one way to make change for 100 cents is to use 4 2-cent pieces, 8 11-cent pieces, 2 38-cent pieces, and 9 -8-cent pieces.
>
> It’s possible to have 0 of some coins, e.g. 50 2-cent pieces is one way to make change for a dollar.
>
> Write a Prolog function called change100(Coins) that begins like this:
>
> > ```
> >   change100([P2, P11, P38, Pn8]) :-
> >        % ...
> > ```
>
> P2 is the number of 2-cent coins, P11 is the number of 11-cent coins, and so on. Keep in mind that, as specified in the problem description, Pn8 is at most 10.

Comment: I wrote a huge blog post a long time ago about the change-making problem in Prolog. Here it is... https://xor0110.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/making-the-change-with-prolog-the-bad-the-ugly-and-the-good/

Answer (score 1):

To be used in numeric inequalities, variables in Prolog must be instantiated.

You code tries to arithmetically compare uninstantiated variables, that's not what Prolog can do.

But you can use so-called "constraint logic programming" - Prolog extension that solves this problem.

Here is the code in SWI-Prolog (almost the same as your original code):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
change100([P2, P11, P38, Pn8]):- 
    Pn8 #=< 10,
    Pn8 #>= 0,
    P2 #>= 0, P11 #>= 0, P38 #>= 0,
    D #= 2 * P2 + 11 * P11 + 38 * P38 - 8 * Pn8,
    D #= 100,
    label([P2, P11, P38, Pn8]).
```

*Update.*

It can be verified that you get 195 different solutions with this program.

You mentioned that there should be 108 different solutions. This number of solutions can be obtained with incorrect assumption that number of a coin times the coin value should be less or equal 100 (i.e. no more then 100/2=50 coins of value 2). This assumption would be correct if we had only positive coins, but for the problem this assumption will lead to omission of "90 * 2 + 0 * 11 + 0 * 38 - 10 * 8", for example.

To emulate this incorrect logic and get 108 solutions you can add `2 * P2 #=< 100, 11 * P11 #=<100, 38 * P38 #=< 100,` line to the program. But please argue that there are really 195 solutions.

Comment: Thank you so much. But if I test the code I got 195 returns, while the correct answer should be 108 different returns. I think I need to add some more constraints into the function.

Comment: @user3221327 there are indeed 195 different solutions, and I think this is correct for the problem formulated in the question. Maybe you missed some important detail from the problem statement?

Comment: Yes, maybe. I need to check it out. Btw if you are interested, I have updated the original problem statement.

Comment: @user3221327 I see the question updated. I would argue that 195 different answers is the correct number for the problem. Why do you think there should be only 108? You can print all answers and manually try to find at least one that is not correct. If there are really 108 correct answers, almost half of 195 would be incorrect, so it should not be hard to find one. But I think all 195 are correct.

Comment: Ha, I've found how one can get 108 (which is incorrect). See my answer updated.